# Logger implementation with log4j2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, log4j

I have a few question to ask about implementing logger with log4j2 .

1. Is `log4j2` still in `beta` release stage ? If so any idea when will
   final release happen ?
2. I noticed there are quite few changes that needs to be done with
   migrating from `log4j1.2` to `log4j2` . So one particular change i
   am conserned with is the following

   `Logger.getLogger must be modified to LogManager.getLogger`.

   So if this is a change then I have to change the static instance such as

   `private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( MyClass.class )` to

   `private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger( MyClass.class )` right?

3.Is there way to write a custom class to call `Logger.getLogger()` and call this custom method in every class for instantiating ?

-Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) As far as I know, future development of log4j is dropped.

The next project is **slf4j**, which is an abstract logger, with the default implementation logback.

2) I don't know if this change is needed, because I use slf4j now.

3) Why do that.. It's only 1 line for the logger object creation. But it is possible yes.

```
class MyLoggerFactory {
    public static Logger getLogger (Class clazz){
        return Logger.getLogger(clazz);
    }
}
```

And called with `MyLoggerFactory.getLogger(this.class);` or something similar. I don't have an IDE right now.